# Cisco VPN, can't connect

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, cisco

First of all, I am a complete novice when it comes to ubuntu (a COMPlETE novice). I did my first installation not more than 2 weeks ago.

To the issue, I'm having problems connecting to our company's VPN. I got the pcf imported and I've installed the network-manager-vpnc. I'm able to type in my password for the connection but it only says that it couldn't connect. I would be fine with this if I knew why it wouldn't connect but I'm not getting any indication on whats wrong.

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I realize the information I'm sharing is very limited but as stated earlier... I'm new to this. What should be the first thing I need to check?